# Add custom out animation on the slide of owl-carousell

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, animate.css

I successfully added a custom **in** animation on the [owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/), but I can't find the right event or way to add a slide **out** animation.

Any ideas or thoughts?

---

Here is custom **in** animation:

```js
var owl = $('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:30,
    smartSpeed:450,
    loop: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
});

owl.on('change.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    var el = event.target;
    $('.m, .c', el).addClass('slideInRight animated')
            .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $('.m, .c', el).removeClass('slideInRight animated');
            });
        });
```

```css
#demos .owl-carousel .item {
  padding: 0 !important;
  display: flex;
  background: none !important;
}

.m-wrapper,
.c-wrapper,
.m,
.c {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.m-wrapper,
.c-wrapper {
  width: 50%
}

.m1 {
  background: blue;
}

.m2 {
  background: red;
}

.m3 {
  background: yellow;
}

.c {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #4DC7A0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
<div class="custom1 owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><div class="m-wrapper"><div class="m m1"></div></div><div class="c-wrapper"><div class="c"><h4>1</h4></div></div>
  </div><div class="item"><div class="m-wrapper"><div class="m m2"></div></div><div class="c-wrapper"><div class="c"><h4>2</h4></div></div>
  </div><div class="item"><div class="m-wrapper"><div class="m m3"></div></div><div class="c-wrapper"><div class="c"><h4>3</h4></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

My aim is to add an `slideOutLeft` animation, so that media (`.m`) and the content (`.c`) element slide out smooth to the left. There are different [events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) like `translate.owl.carousel` but it seems like they are not firing in the right moment.

Comment: is that are you looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/rafahell/arzcwL4h/

Comment: @rafahell kind of, the sliding-out is correct, but it should be seamless with slide-in animation. There should be no white in between. As far as I see, does your [code](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/mk9sf1tw/1/) you just set a delayed slide-out. I'm not sure, if that is the right way to get that smooth.

Comment: is kind of trick because you will need to add an animation before the slide change to another slide and this is why I've used the setitimeout. Probably has a better solution for that.